# How to develop neural network using tf.layers.dense and ‎tf.data.Dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, feed-forward

I have two features X1 & X2 and want to predict Y.

**Train Data**

```
X1  X2   Y
11  610 676
52  557 120
78  491 964
77  380 722
24  464 837
86  532 601
99  580 452
10  539 200
88  507 756
```

How do I do this using tf.layers.dense & tf.data.Dataset? Pls do not use feed_dict since its not recommended anymore.

*I searched for good code sample which uses both tf.layers.dense & tf.data.Dataset but didnt anything solid.*

Once the model is trained I would like to predict Y for the below test data. Is dataset.make_initializable_iterator() required for predicting on test data?

**Test Data**

```
X1  X2
36  608
48  170
58  455
99  927
13  431
61  312
34  763
94  626
14  193
```

It will be an addon if model architecture includes batch normalization, regularization and dropout but not a priority right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial from towardsdatascience is pretty good explaining the usage of the dataset API 
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428

Relevant Jupyter notebook 
https://github.com/FrancescoSaverioZuppichini/Tensorflow-Dataset-Tutorial/blob/master/dataset_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: I saw these links before. They dont have code on how to apply the model on test data to make new predictions..

Comment: @ML_Pro It's included in both the tutorial and the notebook using a `generic iterator` :)

Comment: No, the links you shared is not showing how we can make predictions on test dataset. I am looking for that. If you know, can you post a working code?

Comment: Please read the article it has an explicit part on how to make a dataset iterator that works on both train and test datasets that you can use in the model it's what is asked in the question about using the tf.dataset API if you want a tutorial on creating a NN in tf you can check tf official docs that have a lot of examples.

Comment: The tutorial only shows how we can create test data using tf.data but doesn't say how to predict on test data using tf.layers. This combination of tf. Data and tf.layers is missing in the tutorial. I have already tried this tutorial. If you have a answer pls post the code and I will accept it as answer